# Angular 4 button with click(returnsbooleanVAR) function and routerlink + boolean VAR timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, routes

I have a button that has a funcion on (click) that sets a variable "routingActivated" true or false and then in the same button a routerlink that links to another component if that var is true.. Everything works fine but in order to go to the next component I have to CLICK twice the button.. Any thoughts of how to re-do it so I only have to click once?

This is the button :

```
<button  (click)="check()"  [routerLink]="routingActivated ? ['/enviando']: []"  >Continue</button>
```

this is the check function that changes the var routingActivated to true or false

```
check():void{
routingActivated =true/false  //depending on a condition 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly redirect in your component

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

export class InfoComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router)

    check():void{
        if(routingActivated) {
            this.router.navigate(['./enviando']);
        }
    }
}
```

and simplify your HTML

```
<button  (click)="check()">Continue</button>
```

Comment: When I add this.router.navigate(['./enviando']); it shows an error:

Property 'router' does not exist on type InfoComponent

Comment: You have to add it in your constructor (see my edit)

Comment: Have added it to the constructor + added the import for router and now .navigate is the problem
it says
Property "navigate" doesnt exist on type of "typeof Router"

Comment: Can you share all your component code and the exact error please ?

Comment: On the constructor I had  private router = Router instead of router:Router